# Reflect Color as BW

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a scene set up with colored spotlights shining on a cube. Beyond the cube is a mirror, which reflects the scene.

I would like the reflected colors to be black and white. The spotlights are standard emission nodes and the mirror is a 0 roughness glossy node.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, using (as I expected) the Glossy Depth output of the Light Path node, connected to the BW node

Comment: You might wish to show you node setup and its result, so that others wishing to achieve the same effect may see how to do it :)